# (Done) Reopen: "How to handle a group activity during an interview..."

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

The question [How to handle a group activity during an interview when the participants are applying for the same job as you?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119611/how-to-handle-a-group-activity-during-an-interview-when-the-participants-are-app) was recently closed for being too broad. Honestly, I have absolutely no idea why. The question is perfectly clear and answerable as is.

I'd like to request that this question be reopened.

Comment: I already voted to re-open it. No idea why it was put on hold. Actually I have an idea, I just don't agree it made sense to put it on hold.

Comment: I cast the last one, feel free to answer it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The post is open again now.

---

I agree that this post is answerable (it already has some) and should be reopened.

Casted the 4th vote...